# Salesforce : Error while deploying Profile in Production

Tags: deployment, salesforce-lightning, user-permissions, user-profile

While deploying Profiles from UAT sandbox to production , encounter below error :
**Unknown user permission: ShareFilesWithNetworks**

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to the profile, and from the System Permission section remove the permission named "Share Files with People in Experience Cloud sites"

That should fix the error

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked after removing the the permission named "Share Files with People in Experience Cloud sites" from the source sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

On Defalt Profiles, it is not posisble to untick the permission mentioned in the accepted answer.
In that case, another solution could be to enable Experiences in the target org. Then, the "Share Files with People in Experience Cloud sites" permission comes available on profile, allowing deployments to recognize and succeed on this permission.